# Setting up Tomcat 8 on a Ubuntu Server hosted by Azure

Tags: azure, ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8

I've created a VM with Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS on Microsoft Azure.
I then installed Tomcat 8 following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial.
I started the Tomcat server and I was able to access it from the local machine

The next step is to access Tomcat from another computer.
I've disabled the firewall using `sudo ufw disable`
I created inbound rules by going on the Azure new portal > select my VM > Network Interfaces > Network Security Rule.
[Security Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QtX4.png)

However when I try to access my server from my computer, it says this site can't be reached...
What am I missing/doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:
Ok so I found the link in comment. I had to create a workers.properties file etc. and now it works... But why?

Comment: Have you modify Tomcat port settings? listening on port 80?

Comment: Tomcat listening on port 8080 by default. please use `netstat -ant` to check which port listening on,

Comment: Yes listening on port 80

Comment: Here's the link about the workers.properties https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/08/18/deploying-an-azure-ubuntu-linux-vm-running-apache-tomcat-for-use-with-visual-studio-team-services-and-team-foundation-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

workers.properties have the information about host address and port information.
The Tomcat worker is a **Tomcat instance** that is waiting to execute servlets or any other content on behalf of some web server.
For example, we can have a web server such as the Apache HTTP Server **forwarding** servlet requests to a Tomcat process (the worker) running behind it.

Comment: please use `netstat -ant` to see tomcat based on IPv4 or IPv6.